# How to add transition effect for dropdown using css

Tags: html, css

Hi am using bootstrap 4 and designed menu bar with caret.

In this code it has dropdown. when the user click the heading like **LAPTOP**,**CAMERA** or **MOBILE**. it list out the products list.  so my requirement was when user click the heading dropdown should have some  smooth transition effect. so please let me know how to achieve that.

```css
.nav-link-type-three {
      padding-right: 2.5rem !important;
      padding-left: 1.5rem !important;
      color: white !important;
      text-decoration: none;
  }
  .nav-link-type-three:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .nav-link-type-three::after,  li.show .nav-link-type-three::after{
    right: -7px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 17px;
    top: 1px;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f0d7";
    position: relative;
  }
  .nav-link-type-three::after,  li.show .nav-link-type-three::after{
    content: "\f0d7";
  }
 li.show .nav-link-type-three::after{
    content: "\f0d8";
    color: #232323;
  }

  .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show>.nav-link-type-three {
      color: #232323 !important;
      text-decoration: none
  }

  .bg-dark-type-three {
      background-color: #29a4d0 !important;
  }
  
  /* Default image size */
      img {

          max-width: 40px;
          min-height: 40px;
      }

      /* images space */
      .col-md-2 {
          margin-left: 2%;
      }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark-type-three">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown nav-org">
  
            <a class="nav-link-type-three nav-org " type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              LAPTOP 
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-one" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                    <div class="text-center">
                      <div>
                        <img src="https://ssl-product-images.www8-hp.com/digmedialib/prodimg/lowres/c05962448.png" alt="">
                      </div>
                      <h6> lg </h6>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                    <div class="text-center">
                      <div>
                        <img src="https://images.idgesg.net/images/article/2017/11/bestbuylenovolaptop-100742402-large.jpg"
                          alt="">
                      </div>
                      <h6> sony </h6>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                    <div class="text-center">
                      <div>
                        <img src="https://www.lenovo.com/medias/lenovo-laptop-legion-y520-15-front.png?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3wyNzI1M3xpbWFnZS9wbmd8aW1hZ2VzL2hiMS9oMDQvOTQxMjY3NTUwMjExMC5wbmd8YjYxMzUxYzUwZDcyNmEyYjJmN2Y1MmQyZTAxYmI4NmY5Yjg4N2Y0ZjIxMWI0YzYyMTM3YTBiZmMyYjZjZGY4Ng"
                          alt="">
                      </div>
                      <h6> acer</h6>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                    <div class="text-center">
                      <div>
                        <img src=" https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/6/4/10180946/u_10180946.jpg" alt="">
                      </div>
                      <h6> dell</h6>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                    <div class="text-center">
                      <div>
                        <img src="https://img-prod-cms-rt-microsoft-com.akamaized.net/cms/api/am/imageFileData/RE2ygZJ?ver=948e&q=90&m=6&h=623&w=767&b=%23FFFFFFFF&l=f&f=jpg&o=t&aim=true"
                          alt="">
                      </div>
                      <h6> HP </h6>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link-type-three " type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              SPEAKERS 
            </a>
  
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-second" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                    <div class="text-center">
                      <div>
                        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ6UE4aUUdaU7m5yO4lG6YvjbAcjRM0sCD5BmzP1PInJ3KcgWwB"
                          alt="">
                      </div>
                      <h6>Mono  </h6>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                    <div class="text-center">
                      <div>
                        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71obbdaLHpL._SX425_.jpg" alt="">
                      </div>
                      <h6>jass </h6>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                    <div class="text-center">
                      <div>
                        <img src="https://images.philips.com/is/image/PhilipsConsumer/SPA25A_94-_FP-global-001?$jpglarge$&wid=1250"
                          alt="">
                      </div>
                      <h6>iBall </h6>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                    <div class="text-center">
                      <div>
                        <img src="http://www.litheaudio.com/user/products/large/Lithe%20Audio/Bluetooth%20ceiling%20speakers/Bluetooth%20speaker%20images_0034_01565_Lithe%20Audio%20Bluetooth%20IP%20Rated%20Bathroom%20Ceiling%20speaker_Cutout[1].jpg"
                          alt="">
                      </div>
                      <h6>Zebronics </h6>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                    <div class="text-center">
                      <div>
                        <img src="https://n3.sdlcdn.com/imgs/e/b/6/QHM602_USB_Mini_Speaker_03332-5c47e.jpg" alt="">
                      </div>
                      <h6>Senizer </h6>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
  
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link-type-three" type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              MOBILES 
            </a>
  
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-third " aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                    <div class="text-center">
                      <div>
                        <img src="https://www.91-img.com/pictures/97744-v1-apple-iphone-7-mobile-phone-large-1.jpg" alt="">
                      </div>
                      <h6> iphone 7</h6>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                    <div class="text-center ">
                      <div>
                        <img src="https://www.gofordigitalindia.com/components/com_djclassifieds/images/item/5/5167_mobile_thb.jpg"
                          alt="">
                      </div>
                      <h6>samsung </h6>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                    <div class="text-center">
                      <div>
                        <img src="https://static.toiimg.com/photo/64792032/Motorola-One.jpg" alt="">
                      </div>
                      <h6> Motorola </h6>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                    <div class="text-center">
                      <div>
                        <img src="https://www.emibaba.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Apple-iPhone-8-64gb-Red.png" alt="">
                      </div>
                      <h6> iphone 6s</h6>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                    <div class="text-center">
                      <div>
                        <img src="http://www.infocusindia.co.in/mobile-phones/img/turbo5.png" alt="">
                      </div>
                      <h6>redmi </h6>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link-type-three" type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              CAMARA 
            </a>
  
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-four" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link-type-three" type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              DESKTOP 
            </a>
  
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-five" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link-type-three" type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              REFURBISHED 
            </a>
  
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-six" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link-type-three" type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              ACCESSORIES 
            </a>
  
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-seven" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link-type-three" type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              MOTHERBOARD 
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-eight" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The [images](https://i.ibb.co/f4SfbdG/2019-02-12-214612.jpg) that you have are timing out

Comment: @zer00ne timing out means actually am new to HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of what you want to do [Drop_Down_transition](https://codepen.io/Madi_Naf/pen/KJBpMZ?editors=1100)

```css
.sub-menu-parent { position: relative; }

.sub-menu { 
  visibility: hidden; /* hides sub-menu */
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-2em);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.3s, z-index 0s linear 0.01s;
}

.sub-menu-parent:focus .sub-menu,
.sub-menu-parent:focus-within .sub-menu,
.sub-menu-parent:hover .sub-menu {
  visibility: visible; /* shows sub-menu */
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.3s; /* this removes the transition delay so the menu will be visible while the other styles transition */
}

/* presentational */
body { padding: 2%; font: 18px/1.4 sans-serif; }

nav a { color: #E00; display: block; padding: 0.5em 1em; text-decoration: none; }
nav a:hover { color: #F55; }
nav ul,
nav ul li { list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; }

nav > ul { background: #EEE; text-align: center; }
nav > ul > li { display: inline-block; border-left: solid 1px #aaa; }
nav > ul > li:first-child { border-left: none; }

.sub-menu {
  background: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<nav>
   <ul>
     <li class="sub-menu-parent" tab-index="0">
       <a href="http://google.com">Menu Item 1</a>
       <ul class="sub-menu">
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="sub-menu-parent" tab-index="0">
       <a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>
       <ul class="sub-menu">
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 6</a></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="sub-menu-parent" tab-index="0">
       <a href="#">Menu Item 3</a>
       <ul class="sub-menu">
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
       </ul></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
```

Comment: yes i have tried this earlier but it doesn't work for me. i don't know whether i have added correct css or not. Actually am new to css Can u please tell me where to add  this code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the media query css in your code. The dropdown animation start from `992px` you can adjust based on your requirement and also change the default `jquery.min` to `3.3.1` to support dropdown animation. I hope this solution will be helpful for you.

```css
.nav-link-type-three {
    padding-right: 2.5rem !important;
    padding-left: 1.5rem !important;
    color: white !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-link-type-three:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-link-type-three::after,
li.show .nav-link-type-three::after {
    right: -7px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 17px;
    top: 1px;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f0d7";
    position: relative;
}

.nav-link-type-three::after,
li.show .nav-link-type-three::after {
    content: "\f0d7";
}

li.show .nav-link-type-three::after {
    content: "\f0d8";
    color: #232323;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show>.nav-link-type-three {
    color: #232323 !important;
    text-decoration: none
}

.bg-dark-type-three {
    background-color: #29a4d0 !important;
}
@media (min-width:992px) {
.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu.show {
    display: block;
    top: 100%;
    visibility: visible;
} 
.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    top: -150px;
    visibility: visible;
}
.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: -150px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 10rem;
    padding: .5rem 0;
    margin: .125rem 0 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
}
 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark-type-three">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown nav-org">

                <a class="nav-link-type-three nav-org " type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              LAPTOP 
            </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-one" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="https://ssl-product-images.www8-hp.com/digmedialib/prodimg/lowres/c05962448.png" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <h6> lg </h6>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="https://images.idgesg.net/images/article/2017/11/bestbuylenovolaptop-100742402-large.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <h6> sony </h6>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="https://www.lenovo.com/medias/lenovo-laptop-legion-y520-15-front.png?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3wyNzI1M3xpbWFnZS9wbmd8aW1hZ2VzL2hiMS9oMDQvOTQxMjY3NTUwMjExMC5wbmd8YjYxMzUxYzUwZDcyNmEyYjJmN2Y1MmQyZTAxYmI4NmY5Yjg4N2Y0ZjIxMWI0YzYyMTM3YTBiZmMyYjZjZGY4Ng" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <h6> acer</h6>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src=" https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/6/4/10180946/u_10180946.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <h6> dell</h6>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="https://img-prod-cms-rt-microsoft-com.akamaized.net/cms/api/am/imageFileData/RE2ygZJ?ver=948e&q=90&m=6&h=623&w=767&b=%23FFFFFFFF&l=f&f=jpg&o=t&aim=true" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <h6> HP </h6>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link-type-three " type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              SPEAKERS 
            </a>

                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-second" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ6UE4aUUdaU7m5yO4lG6YvjbAcjRM0sCD5BmzP1PInJ3KcgWwB" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <h6>Mono  </h6>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71obbdaLHpL._SX425_.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <h6>jass </h6>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="https://images.philips.com/is/image/PhilipsConsumer/SPA25A_94-_FP-global-001?$jpglarge$&wid=1250" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <h6>iBall </h6>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="http://www.litheaudio.com/user/products/large/Lithe%20Audio/Bluetooth%20ceiling%20speakers/Bluetooth%20speaker%20images_0034_01565_Lithe%20Audio%20Bluetooth%20IP%20Rated%20Bathroom%20Ceiling%20speaker_Cutout[1].jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <h6>Zebronics </h6>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="https://n3.sdlcdn.com/imgs/e/b/6/QHM602_USB_Mini_Speaker_03332-5c47e.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <h6>Senizer </h6>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link-type-three" type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              MOBILES 
            </a>

                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-third " aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="https://www.91-img.com/pictures/97744-v1-apple-iphone-7-mobile-phone-large-1.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <h6> iphone 7</h6>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                                <div class="text-center ">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="https://www.gofordigitalindia.com/components/com_djclassifieds/images/item/5/5167_mobile_thb.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <h6>samsung </h6>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="https://static.toiimg.com/photo/64792032/Motorola-One.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <h6> Motorola </h6>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="https://www.emibaba.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Apple-iPhone-8-64gb-Red.png" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <h6> iphone 6s</h6>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-three-effect" href="#">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="http://www.infocusindia.co.in/mobile-phones/img/turbo5.png" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <h6>redmi </h6>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link-type-three" type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              CAMARA 
            </a>

                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-four" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link-type-three" type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              DESKTOP 
            </a>

                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-five" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link-type-three" type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              REFURBISHED 
            </a>

                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-six" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link-type-three" type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              ACCESSORIES 
            </a>

                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-seven" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link-type-three" type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              MOTHERBOARD 
            </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-eight" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: It was not working for me. By using css we can achieve ah?

Comment: @smithhari Yes. Can achieve using css. I have updated with new code.